# Kdb/q: Function output returning 'length error when querying table

Tags: kdb

I have a table called DATA that looks like this:

| StartDate | EndDate | NAME | TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023.05.05 | 2023.09.18 | Ash | A |
| 2023.01.01 | 2023.05.04 | Ash | B |
| 2023.07.03 | 2023.09.18 | May | C |
| 2023.03.21 | 2023.07.02 | May | D |

I have another table with more data, but only has the Name, and I need to get the type based on the date.

For example:

fGetType[`Ash, 2023.09.01] --I expect--> A

fGetType[`May, 2023.23.03] --I expect--> D

I have a function that looks like this:

```
fGetType:{[Name; Date]
    output: select STARTDATE, ENDDATE, NAME, TYPE from DATA where NAME = Name;
    output: update ValidDate: `Valid from output where Date within (STARTDATE; ENDDATE);
    output: select TYPE from output where ValidDate = `Valid;
    output[0]`TYPE}
```

I call this function like below, so that I can pass in both items in a row at the same time:

```
fGetType'[Name; Date]
```

However, I get the following error message:

```
'length
  [3]  P:\git\home\utils\myqfile.q:106: fGetType:{[Name; Date]
    output: select STARTDATE, ENDDATE, NAME, TYPE from DATA where NAME = Name;
                   ^
    output: update ValidDate: `Valid from output where Date within (STARTDATE; ENDDATE);
```

I am struggling to make sense of this message, as I've tried manually using this function and it seems to work fine. Can someone please help to shed some light on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: To add, if I try to cast the two name variables (because they are symbols) using "$NAME = "$Name, I get a type error under the second $ sign

Comment: That error is due to missing brackets, should be ``(`$NAME)=`$NAME``. This is because q reads code from right to left.

Answer (score 1):

Just a few wholehearted comments in general

- In KBD/Q we normally don't use all capital column names or variable names. An exception would be when a variable is a constant.
- You shouldn't use TYPE, even if it's all capitals. type is a keyword in KDB/Q https://code.kx.com/q/ref/type/
- regarding your comment for casting "$NAME = "$Name is completely wrong and  makes no sense in KDB/Q. you would cast a string to a symbol with `$"HelloWorld" where the backtick is the symbol type to be casted to https://code.kx.com/q4m3/7_Transforming_Data/#732-creating-symbols-from-strings
- have you tried reading Q for Mortals or at least the reference card? https://code.kx.com/q/ref/ https://code.kx.com/q4m3/

Now regarding your initial question
f{}'[Name;Date] the `'` operator is each-both, do the variables Name and Date have the same length?

Below code works for me. Does it solve what you are looking for?

```
q)data:([] startDate:2023.05.05 2023.01.01 2023.07.03 2023.03.21; endDate:2023.09.18 2023.05.04 2023.09.18 2023.07.02; name:`Ash`Ash`May`May; category:`A`B`C`D)
q)data
startDate  endDate    name category
-----------------------------------
2023.05.05 2023.09.18 Ash  A
2023.01.01 2023.05.04 Ash  B
2023.07.03 2023.09.18 May  C
2023.03.21 2023.07.02 May  D

q){[x;y] first select from data where x within (startDate;endDate),name=y}'[2023.01.02 2023.07.04;`Ash`May]
startDate  endDate    name category
-----------------------------------
2023.01.01 2023.05.04 Ash  B
2023.07.03 2023.09.18 May  C

q){[x;y] exec first category from data where x within (startDate;endDate),name=y}'[2023.01.02 2023.07.04;`Ash`May]
`B`C
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer you have supplied and the fact you are using `fGetType'[Name; Date]` for each row it is possible that you are passing `Name` as list rather than an atom. Have a look at this example using the modified table Alex provided:

```
data:([] startDate:2023.05.05 2023.01.01 2023.07.03 2023.03.21; endDate:2023.09.18 2023.05.04 2023.09.18 2023.07.02; name:`Ash`Ash`May`May; category:`A`B`C`D)

/ length error when using a list
{select from data where name=x}[(),`Ash]
'length
  [1]  {select from data where name=x}
                                    ^

/ no error when in replaces =
{select from data where name in x}[(),`Ash]
startDate  endDate    name category
-----------------------------------
2023.05.05 2023.09.18 Ash  A
2023.01.01 2023.05.04 Ash  B
```

You can verify by checking the `meta` of your table to see if the names are enlisted.

Answer (score -1):

So after a few hours of debugging and trying out different things, it looks like this worked:

```
fGetType:{[Name; Date]
    output: select STARTDATE, ENDDATE, NAME, TYPE from DATA where NAME in (Name);
    output: update ValidDate: `Valid from output where Date within (STARTDATE; ENDDATE);
    output: select TYPE from output where ValidDate = `Valid;
    output[0]`TYPE}
```

I don't understand why, as they're both symbols. If anyone has any insight, please let me know.